# Given an array as a string, how to best convert that to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, type-conversion

In JavaScript, given an array as a string:

```
example1: "[1, 2, 3]"
example2: "[]"
example3: "["apple", true, 42]"
```

what is the best way to convert it to an array without JSON.parse?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). It takes a JSON string as a parameter and returns the structure depicted by it.

Alternatively, you could use `eval()` (*but I don't recommend this*)

```js
var json = '["apple", true, 42]';

console.log(json);
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
console.log(eval(json));
```

Comment: Of course. I was looking for another method though. I will amend the original question.

Comment: @campallison Can you explain why? That's an unusual requirement.

Comment: In the process of learning JS I've been recreating some of the built-in methods. In this particular instance, I am trying to see if I can build a JSON parser with decent speed (can handle large data sets). I believe you are right that using anything but JSON.parse in any real application would be unadvisable.

Comment: @campallison Interesting idea, but if you want to do this for the learning experience, why don't you give your attempt first in the question? Or if you already have working code, post under "Answer Your Own Question".

Comment: I posted an answer above. Care to take a look and advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this :

```
var ar = '["bonjour", true, 42]';
function reduce(element, index, array){
  if (index === 0) return element.slice(2, -1);
  if (index === array.length - 1) return element.slice(1, -1);
  return element;
}
var map = ar.split(",").map(reduce)
console.log(map); // [ 'bonjour', ' true', '42' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution using eval() as suggested by @4castle.

```
function parser(str) {
    return eval('(' + str + ')');
}
```

Comment: That will work! Adding parentheses to the string probably isn't necessary.

Comment: eval(str) worked on everything except curly-bracket objects. But yes, eval(str) works on an array, and does not need the parentheses.